# Using fsockopen to POST to a GET query URL

Tags: php, post, get, fsockopen

Whats wrong with this raw HTTP call using fsockopen?

```
POST /api/?action=report HTTP/1.1
Host: www.webhosting-performance.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Conent-Length: 9
Connection: close

test=test
```

The remote script says var_dump($_POST) is empty.

A snippet of my php code looks like this:

```
if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen') > 0) {

  $parts = parse_url($url);
  $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

  if (!$fp) throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $errstr");

  $post_string = $post_fields ? http_build_query($post_fields) : '';

  $out = ($post_string ? "POST " : "GET ") . $parts['path'] . ((isset($parts['query'])) ? "?" . $parts['query'] : false) ." HTTP/1.1\r\n"
       . "Host: ". $parts['host'] ."\r\n"
       . ($post_string ? "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" : false)
       . "Conent-Length: ". strlen($post_string) ."\r\n"
       . "Connection: close\r\n"
       . "\r\n" . $post_string;

  fwrite($fp, $out);

  // ...

} else {
  // use curl
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically just have a typo:

```
Conent-Length: 9
```

See the missing `t` in `Content-Length:`

The real question is (not to malign your efforts at constructing something yourself), why aren't you using [cURL](http://php.net/cURL) or [PEARs HTTP Request](http://www.google.com/search?q=PEAR%20HTTP%20Request) class?

Comment: Years of experience, and such a nagging little typo. I sat for hours trying to solve this. Mistakingly kept copying that typo. Thanks a lot for saving me from doing it for another hour ;) Cheers

Comment: As for your other question. I am trying to do it as native as possible incase extensions are not supported on customer platforms. As for this function, it supports curl if allow_url_fopen is disabled. And I might add PEARs as well.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use [`PEAR::Http_Request2`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php)?